# How to use a Dupligroup as a hair Object

Tags: particles, dupli-groups

I have an empty that is duplicating a group. I would like to instance this empty as the object of a hair particle system (or as part of a group of object's being instanced). This does not appear to work correctly.

1. Please confirm that this is the case and whether this is a bug or the intended behavior.
2. If this is intended behavior, please specify why this is the case and whether this has been thoroughly contemplated.
3. If possible, please specify the person(s) contributing to the particle system and dupligroup implementations.

Dupligroups are a fundamental facet of managing mesh hierarchies and building objects as they are a fundamental way of instancing meshs. They are also critical for sharing assets between files with linking.

I wish to instance trees using the hair particle system. As you can imagine, a complex trees would not be optimal to distribute as a single mesh and would be convenient to instance as a dupligroup.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for not using Group in the particle system rather than complicating matters with an empty? http://i.imgur.com/lNZTzAw.png

Comment: 1.  That doesn't work. It may be because the group is linked. 2. I want to use the random settings of Particle System dupligroup to instance from a variety of dupligroups as specified in the OP.

Comment: Pick Random does just that. By linked do you mean linked from another .blend? I can't say if that's why it doesn't work, but objects linked from other .blends can only be edited in the .blend where they're linked from. Unless it's necessary to have the link intact, you could try append instead. That imports a copy rather than linking to the original object.

Comment: I appreciate your help SixthofFour but I am not an amateur blender user. I am aware of what I'm doing if you read my posts you will see you are stating the obvious (eg, the random feature of particle system Dupligroup, selects a random object of a group to instance. I want one of those said objects to be a group duplicating empty, hence this question). I will shortly attach a blend of this behavior. With regards to what doesn't work, if I select whole object of a Particle System dupligroup, not all of the objects of the group are duplicated.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the line about sharing assets. My bad. I think I saw something about a plug-in that lets you edit linked objects not long ago. I don't remember where though, but perhaps someone else knows about it.

Comment: Linked objects . . . you can make a proxy using `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`P`, or make it local using `P` >  *Selected Objects*

Comment: NoviceInDisguise... I'm confused by how that is useful in this case. Again... 1. I'm trying to hair object a dupligroup empty. 2. There appears to be a bug with the fact that linked groups do not in all instances have all their object's used by the Particle System dupligroup which may be what you are referring to. In some cases they are processed correctly but I have an instance where it is. I dont know what the deterministic behavior is. This is an incidental bug that I don't particularly care about in this workflow. I am more interested in using a dupligroup empty as a hair object.

Comment: I created a bug report: https://developer.blender.org/T44963?workflow=create